# Do you really need a visa to transfer through Heathrow?

Tags: transit-visas, lhr

My wife and step-daughter, both from the Philippines, wonder if they can go via London Heathrow when going from Oslo, Norway, back to Manila, Philippines.  There are SO many rumours that you'll need a VISA just for transfer, so what is the FACT?  They are Philippine citizens, with a valid visa for Norway/Schengen (BUT the old one is expired, and the new one not in their Passports yet...) if THAT matters - and on their way back to their homeland.  They'll go with a SAS-flight from Oslo to Heathrow, and a Catay Pacific from Heathrow to Manila.
Will they need any VISA for the transfer...?